# Unable to find a specification for [PUBLIC POD] depended upon by [PRIVATE POD]

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I'm creating a private pod to handle all common code used in my projects. This private pod has several subspecs on his podspec and one of them depends of a well known public pod: AFNetworking.

On my podspec I have this

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "NAME"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "SUMMARY"
  s.description  = "DESCRIPTION"
  s.homepage     = "https://myhomepage.com"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.author       = { "Me" => "me@myemail.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "https://repositorywithmyprivatepodcode", :tag => s.version }

  s.subspec 'Core' do |cs|
    cs.source_files  = "Source/Core/**/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec 'Resized' do |rs|
    rs.source_files  = "Source/Resized/**/*.{h,m}"
    rs.dependency 'NAME/Core'
    rs.dependency 'AFNetworking' , '~> 3.0'
  end

  s.subspec 'UI' do |us|
    us.source_files  = "Source/UI/**/*.{h,m}"
  end
end
```

I have this code on the Podfile of the project where I'm trying to use the 
"Resized" subspec

```
source 'https://repositorywithmyprivatepodcode'

target 'TestProject' do
  pod 'Square1/Resized'
end
```

But I'm getting this error when running `pod install`

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `AFNetworking` depended upon by `Square1/Resized`
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Is there `=` between `rs.dependency` and the dependency?

Comment: No, there is no need for that `=`, as you can see here https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html

Comment: Did you find fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my problem was that I didn't include the Cocoapods master repository on my project's Podfile.

> The official CocoaPods source is implicit. Once you specify another
>   source, then it will need to be included.

So I changed my Podfile to include it

```
source 'https://bitbucket.org/square1mobileteam/square1-specs'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

And it works.

Comment: Could have it been also fixed bit explictly giving the source of your private pods insteasd and leaving the default CocoaPods source?: `pod 'Square1/Resized', :git => 'https://repositorywithmyprivatepodcode'`?

Comment: No, cocoapods doesn't allow to set the source inside a subspec. If you try that you'll see that after executing `pod repo lint` you get an error.